# Compare Two Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two pivot tables, one in Column A, one in Column B, and they are formatted the same way.

The pivot tables have a list of Users, and under each User a list of IDs.

Is there a way I can compare the two pivot tables against each other? I want to match Users in both tables and see which Users have duplicate IDs.

To help visualize, the tables look something like this:

Table 1

```
-------------------------                                          
| DAVE  | asgh4 | lshg8 |                                         
| MATT  | 39f8  | 2352  |                                               
-------------------------
```

Table 2

```
-------------------------
| PETER | dgghn  | lkasj|
| DAVE  | asgh4  | 38gfj|
-------------------------
```

I want to see matches like "DAVE" and "asgh4" because the user matches and the ID matches. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two broad ways to achieve this without VBA. The first is to create a 'helper column' next to each pivot table. In that column, starting at row 1 and dragged down, type (Assuming the name is in column A and the ID is in column B)

```
=A1&B1
```

Then with that done in both tables, use the MATCH function to determine if any of the NAME&ID strings matches, like so, starting in cell D1 on sheet1 (assuming the NAME&ID string is in column C):

```
=match(C1,Sheet2!C:C,0)
```

If it shows a number, that means there was a match found in the other sheet. If it shows N/A#, then there was no match found. To clean it up a bit, wrap that in the function ISERROR, like so:

```
=iserror(match(C1,Sheet2!C:C,0))
```

If it says TRUE in a cell, that means the MATCH function found no matching data, which creates an error. If it says FALSE, that means there was a match found, meaning there is a duplicate value.

Alternatively, you can do this without creating helper columns, but I don't recommend if you are unfamiliar with array formulas.

Put this formula in Sheet1, cell C1, and drag down (when the formula is typed, confirm by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, instead of just ENTER):

```
=iserror(match(A1&B1,sheet2!A1:A100&sheet2!B1:B100))
```

Note that with an array function you must specify how far down your column goes, or performance will lag significantly.