# Excel Pivot Tables Include Relatively Missing Fields

Tags: excel

I have two tables:

TABLE 1

| Zone | Proj. |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | 22 |
| Gamma | 23 |

TABLE 2

| Zone | Real |
| --- | --- |
| Kappa | 37 |
| Gamma | 25 |

I am pivoting these tables side by side for contrasting the difference between projection and real values. Now, I want both of these pivots to contain the union of `Zones` found in both the sheets and fill corresponding `Sales` with something like `N.A.` or `0`, if not found in the respective source.

PIVOT 1

| Zone | Proj. |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | 22 |
| Gamma | 23 |
| Kappa | N.A. |

PIVOT 2

| Zone | Real |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | N. A |
| Gamma | 25 |
| Kappa | 37 |

I am aware of `LOOKUP` etc. (or `LEFT JOINS` using ETL tools) but looking at a "cleaner" and "easier" option.

**Use-case**: I have two tables—one with annual sales data of about a few thousand sales agents and another with their predictions, as generated last year—but the prediction table lacks rows for 6-7 customers in the second table. So, when I pivot both on the same worksheet, the visual harmony gets disturbed once a missing row is encountered.

Comment: Have you tried using the Power Query here, ? Upload both table to PQ, create connection and merge queries as new with Left Outer Join, to compare.

Comment: I can use that or other ETL tools but I wonder if there's some less-popular feature in Excel.

Comment: I found one query on the topic you have posted, you may find this useful, [Compare_Pivot_Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300092/compare-two-pivot-tables)